# How does a cpu represent bits?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, logic-gates, microprocessor, cpu

Maybe my question was asked earlier, but I want info away from logical abstractions, in different contrast.

START:

- A transistor can represent two states - on and off - means 1 and 0 - means 1bit.
- So why we don't use only 32 transistors to represent 32-bit data?
- Why are there logic gates which contain normally 2-8 transistors in each to represent 1 bit only in each gate, which commonly input 2 bits and output 1 bit?
- What type of input bits are they and why only one output?
- Then how do we use that one output further?
- Why do we degrade 2 bits to one?

END

Summary: I need a very lowest possible physical structure of CPU - starts from a transistor to assembly, without any abstract terminologies. I read many tutorials on the web but I couldn't understand. That is why I am here.

Comment: Start with the digital logic chapters in "The Art of Electronics". You may need a couple of the earlier chapters on basic electronics and transistor operation to mate sense of them.

Comment: it is practically impossible to completely understand a CPU at transistor level because of the number of transistors involved, and it is pointless to even try because the cpu was not designed at transistor level by a human ... the transistor level design was done by a machine

Comment: If you want a complete description, read Code by Charles Petzold. You might be able to find an old copy floating about on the web, if you can’t get hold of the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary data is represented by signals, not transistors. A signal could be two different voltage levels (e.g., +5V represents 1, 0V represents 0 is very common), or the presence/absence of a current, or sometimes the polarity of a magnetic field.

Transistors can be used to amplify signals, so yes, a transistor can be in one of two states, based on its input signal. But that doesn't mean that a single transistor can store or remember the value of a bit on its own.

Similarly, logic gates do not "represent" bits. They are used to transform data by performing useful Boolean operations on their input signals to produce an output signal. We do not normally think of this as "degrading" the data.

Overall, your question (how to [build a CPU from transistors](https://monster6502.com/)) is far too broad for this site. I just wanted to address some of your fundamental misconceptions.

And you can't avoid "abstractions", either. A CPU is a complex piece of logic that can only be understood via the lower-level abstractions — transistors form gates; gates form higher level functions like registers, multiplexers and ALUs; a CPU is a collection of those functions.

---

Followup questions:

> 1. which things physically convert these signal into usable info?

Basically, it's all about switches and lights. For example, when you press the "a" key on your computer keyboard, you're simply closing a switch, allowing a current to flow where it couldn't before. Software in the computer "knows" that this particular switch represents your idea of the letter "a". After a whole bunch of hardware and software operations, the computer eventually turns on and off a bunch of lights (pixels on your display) by changing the voltage on them, and you recognize that pattern of dots as an approximation of the letter "a".

> 2. I didn't mean that a transistor store data, but I just mean that a transistor can hold a bit for a specific time.

No, transistors don't "hold" anything. For all practical purposes, they react immediately to any change in input.

> 3. why we use a logic gate to convert 2 signals into one signal?

Because that's a useful thing to do at the lowest level in order to accomplish the higher-level goals of the circuit or machine you're building. Boolean algebra and 2's-complement arithmetic provide the basis for representing useful mathematical and data-handling concepts as binary data.

> even when a transistor can directly represent 2 types of signals? why we dont use that 2 states directly from a transistor, but by the use of logic gates in between.

Now we're just heading off into the weeds. Gates are made of transistors. So if you're using gates, you're using transistors. They aren't two distinct entities.

Comment: which is the first lowest level abstraction used in low level physical structure of cpu? i understand this sequence till now. 
...-> ... -> transistors -> two states -> signals-> ... -> ... -> binary->... -> ... please fill missing things in the sequence ...

Comment: The lowest level abstraction is the first thing I said: representing binary data as two voltage levels, two amounts of current, or the polarity of a magnetic field. Binary data *itself* is an abstraction. Everything else is electrical signals, circuits to manipulate those signals, and then interpreting the output signals as new binary data.

Comment: first thank to edit my question. second thanks to answer my stupid question. third advance thanks to further explaination.  1: which things physically convert these signal into usable info? 2: i didnt mean that a transistor store data but i just mean that can a transistor hold a bit for a specific time?. 3: why we use a logic gate to convert 2 signals into one signal? even when a transistor can directly represent 2 types of signals? why we dont use that 2 states directly from a transistor, but by the use of logic gates in between .

Comment: You are great! Now i understand a lot of things which help me to understand other tutorials on internet. Sir , any tutorial/Book recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

> A transistor can represent two states - on and off - means 1 and 0 -
>   means 1bit. So why we don't use only 32 transistors to represent
>   32-bit data? Why are there logic gates which contain normally 2-8
>   transistors in each to represent 1 bit only in each gate, which
>   commonly input 2 bits and output 1 bit?

A transistor cannot represent two states. It can, however, be used as one component within a larger circuit and that circuit can represent two states.

There's plenty of existing text on the 'design of logic gates' on the Internet that will cover this in great detail this for you.

Comment: If i could understand these lowest level physical structure of cpu on internet so why would i need to ask this question here.

Comment: @EZRA, you're mistaken about what 'here' does, then. This site is not an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand, or a source of free discussion tutorials. You will have to explore and learn further from this using your own self-discipline.

Comment: so what 'here' does! ur rite. this site is not technical encyclopedia but as i know this site is not a static site like encyclopedia. This is a dynamic site which generate content from noobs like me and experts like @Dave Tweed. These discussions make search engines index more Keywords/Text from this site and when any noob new to digital electronic, like me search on google , they found these helpful answers/discussions and this site will progress more. Question is alway asked by the learner who dont know about how things work in specific discipline.

Comment: @EZRA, your question has been closed. Learning requires a good attitude and fewer long speeches.

Answer (score 0):

this stores 1 bit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ71Ji.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>